# Class as return value in method?

Tags: java, return, return-type

How do you create the return of a method that has the return type as the class? This is a method to find the sum of two numbers. The number object is created in another class, and it has to be added to the 'other' parameter. I am not sure if I am creating the method properly. And how would you create the proper return if the type is the class?

```
public class Number {
    private double a;
    private double b;

    public Number (double _a, double _b) {
            a = _a;
            b = _b;
    }

    public Number sum(Number other) {
            a = this.a + other.b;
            b = this.b + other.b;
            return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend changing the names of `_a` and `_b`. You can use `a` and `b` and write `this.a = a;`.

Comment: Although the question is very basic and OP could have found the answer if he read a basic tutorial, but it's well asked, +1 for clarity and well writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you create the return of a method that has the return type as the class?

The same way you handle any other use of a reference.

In your case you *could* just change your code to:

```
return this;
```

However, that's *adding* the given number to the existing one, mutating the object that you call the method on... a bit like `StringBuilder.append`.

I suspect it would be better not to change either number, but instead create a new one:

```
public Number sum(Number other) {
    return new Number(this.a + other.a, this.b + other.b);
}
```

(Currently you're not using `other.a` at all, but I assume that was a typo.)

Aside from anything else, that way you can make your type *immutable*, which generally makes things easier to reason about. To do that, make the fields `final` and make the class `final` too. I would personally change the method name to `plus` as well, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can return the object of type class only.

```
public Number sum(Number other,Number nobj) {
        a = nobj.a + other.b;
        b = nobj.b + other.b;
        return nobj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is returning the same type that was passed to the sum method (including subclasses), you can inspect the the argument and return one of that type.

Something like...

```
public class Number {
    private double a;
    private double b;

    private Number () {}
    public Number (double _a, double _b) {
            a = _a;
            b = _b;
    }

    public Number sum(Number other) throws Exception {
            a = this.a + other.b;
            b = this.b + other.b;
            Number n = other.getClass().newInstance();
            n.a = a;
            n.b = b;
            return n;
    }
}
```

Note I had to add a no-arg constructor too.